# Excel VBA Placing "Empty" Commas at end of CSV File

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to place 7 commas at the end of a CSV file in order to meet criteria. I have placed a comma in the last cell in order to give me a total of 7 commas for the unused fields, but it yields a comma surrounded by quotes when viewed in Notepad.
Here is an example of what I get in Notepad:
63908-0410001,0,3/13/2015,100.0000,7,0,62,,,,RADIO1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2037,,,,,,,","

How can I get the commas I need without the quotes?

```
Range("AJ1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ","
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AJ1:AJ" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("AJ1:AJ" & LR).Select
```

Comment: I swear I tried that 3 different times and it never worked until I tried it this time. An internet cookie for you.

Comment: I posted an answer as I thought I could trim your 4 lines of code into 1

Comment: You may have to refresh the page to see the answer. Also... I love cookies :P

Comment: @SethO: On your code, can you try with ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace those 4 lines of code with (Untested)

```
Range("AJ1:AJ" & LR).Formula = " "
```

Comment: I think you can use `.Formula = """"""` too if you don't want the spaces, as Excel should treat the quotation marks as qualifying text, and "" isn't a null string. (not tested though)

Comment: Tight code. I love it. The solution is already off to the customer, but thanks so much for your help. I have not tried to write anything in VB since college.